# db4o development tools and resources?

Tags: database, db4o

Since the 7.x versions of db4o ObjectManager are only available as a commercial product (very expensive!) are there any alternative tools that are available to inspect/explore db4o 7.x databases?

Also, what other tools would you recommend to a beginning db4o developer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the object manager is now free:

[Object Manager Enterprise Now Free To All Developers](http://developer.db4o.com/blogs/product_news/archive/2009/01/25/object-manager-enterprise-now-free-to-all-developers.aspx)

I want to give it a try!